# Link image array to a url

Tags: php, arrays, image, hyperlink

How would I link each image in the array below to different pages?
The array displays various banners on the website. I want each banner to link to a different page on the website. 
for example small_header_01.jpg links to aboutus.html

```
$banner_small_images = array('small_header_01.jpg',
                             'small_header_02.jpg',
                             'small_header_03.jpg',
                             'small_header_04.jpg',
                             'small_header_05.jpg');
```

Comment: What do you mean by link? What are the different pages you want to link them to? What have you tried, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: the array displays various banners on the website. I want each banner to link to a different page on the website. for example small_header_01.jpg links to aboutus.html

Comment: You need to add that information to your question - is there another array with page information in it? Do you need to work out the link based on the name? Will there ever be more than 5 images?

Comment: All you need is http://codepad.org/moSoO52S

Comment: You need to either add more information to your array to know where each image should link to or add another array with the links. I prefer option number one. Then you can use $banner_small_images[0]['link'] to get the links.

Comment: no there isn't another array with page info. I don't need to work out the link based on the name. The image could link to another website. There will not be more than 5 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a link, you need a link location right? And your array does not provide link location. But you can fix that.

To do this you can build array like this:

```
    $links = array(
    'www.link01.com' => 'small_header_01.jpg',
    'www.link02.com' => 'small_header_02.jpg',
    'www.link03.com' => 'small_header_03.jpg',
    'www.link04.com' => 'small_header_04.jpg',
    'www.link05.com' => 'small_header_05.jpg',
);
```

Now you have array that holds image with appropriate link location. You stored you link location in array key, and image location in array value.

From there you can loop through all array items and print your links like this:

```
foreach($links as $link => $image) {
    echo "<a href='http://{$link}'><img src='{$image}'></img></a><br />";   
}
```

Or you could use two arrays, one holding links, and the other one holding images, and then combine them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. One way would be to create another array of links, and then use array_combine to make a new array that contains link=>image. Then when you loop through you have a key and value tied together to use however you want to. Something like:

```
foreach($newarray as $key => $value){
  print '<a href="'.$key.'"><img src="'.$value.'"/></a>';
}
```